# How can I force Firebase Realtime Database URL without "default-rtdb"

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

My realtime database URL is like https://myprojectid.firebaseio.com

When I start my node.js server I have error message :

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure
> that you have the URL of your Firebase Realtime Database instance
> configured correctly.
> (https://myprojectid-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/)

My Firebase config is :

```
# Firebase
apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
authDomain=myprojectid.firebaseapp.com
databaseURL=https://myprojectid.firebaseio.com
projectId=myprojectid
storageBucket=myprojectid.appspot.com
messagingSenderId=00000000000000
appId=1:0000000000000:web:000000000000000
```

When I'm trying to debug npm library, I can see that namespace is indeed "myprojectid-default-rtdb" but can't find where to change it.

I tried to set databaseURL with query string ?ns=myprojectid but not better.

By searching on Google I could read :

> For recently created Firebase projects the default database URI
> usually has the format https://
> -default-rtdb.firebaseio.com. Databases in projects
> created before September 2020 had the default database URI
> https://.firebaseio.com. For backward compatibility
> reasons, if you don’t specify a database URI, the SDK will use the
> project ID defined in the Service Account JSON file to automatically
> generate it

Could you help me to find a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change the name of the default database instance that is created in your Firebase project. If your project is on the paid plan, you can add additional database instances where you fully control the name, but not for the default one.

You will have to update your project configuration to use the correct database URL. If the database in the US data center, that'd be:

```
databaseURL=https://myprojectid-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
```

Comment: I already have databaseURL configured without *default-rtdb* as I mentionned, but it is not taken into account.